# Implementing a prefix notation expression parser using Irony

Tags: c#, expression-trees, prefix, irony

I'm trying to parse user-inputted prefix notation logical expressions using a context-free-grammar with the Irony library. This is for a class assignment so if anybody happens to be an expert on this, I would love to know more.

I need to accept a user-inputted logical expression of the following format:

```
and P Q -- (meaning P ^ Q)
or P Q -- (meaning P v Q)
not P  -- (meaning ~P)
imp P Q -- (meaning P -> Q)
```

I'm attempting to parse these into expression trees using a context free grammar I'm implementing in Irony. The context-free grammar I'm using is here, in BNF:

```
<Expression> ::= <Not> | <And> | <Or> | <Implies> | <Identifier>
<Not>        ::= "not" <Expression>
<And>        ::= "and" <Expression> <Expression>
<Or>         ::= "or" <Expression> <Expression>
<Implies>    ::= "imp" <Expression> <Expression>

(<Identifier> is implemented as an IdentifierTerminal object).
```

I've used Irony to parse expressions before but for some reason, I cannot get it to work. When I type the expression `and P Q` it seems to be identifying "and" as an Identifier terminal, not part of the And nonterminal. I may be doing something obvious but I simply can't figure it out. Here is the language class I extended:

```csharp
class LogicPrefix : Grammar
{
    public LogicPrefix()
        : base(false)
    {
        NonTerminal Expression = new NonTerminal("expression");
        NonTerminal Implies = new NonTerminal("implies");
        NonTerminal And = new NonTerminal("and");
        NonTerminal Or = new NonTerminal("or");
        NonTerminal Not = new NonTerminal("not");
        Terminal Identifier = new IdentifierTerminal("identifier");
        Root = Expression;

        Expression.Rule = And | Or | Not | Identifier;

        Not.Rule = "not" + Expression;
        Implies.Rule = "imp" + Expression + Expression;
        And.Rule = "and" + Expression + Expression;
        Or.Rule = "or" + Expression + Expression;

    }
}
```

And here is my driver class:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LogicPrefix grammar = new LogicPrefix();
        Parser p = new Parser(grammar);
        ParseTree pt = p.Parse("and P Q");
        //pt has thrown an error flag.
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong, I'd love some advice on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your identifier lexing seems to allow your other terminals to be lexed as identifiers because by definition `IdentifierTerminal` recognizes anything that "starts with an underscore or letter and contains only letters, numbers, and underscores" ([source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Irony_-_Language_Implementation_Kit/Grammar/Terminals#IdentifierTerminal)). This means that when your program reads the `and`, it can read it as the identifier `and` or the keyword `and`.

It looks to me like you can fix this by declaring your operators to be punctuation with the following line:

```
MarkPunctuation("imp", "and", "or", "not")
```

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thanks. I also had to remove the spaces in the rules for And, Or, Not, and Implies. That was an error on my part.